# How to add delay using setTimeout for every iteration?

Tags: javascript

This creates a 2 second delay and runs the loop. I need to create a 2 second delay for every iteration, not just once.

```
var myArray = ['test1','test2','test3'];

function doSetTimeout(index) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(myArray[index]) }, 2000);
}

var index;
for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index) {    
    doSetTimeout(index)
}
```

Expected result would be:

```
test1 
(2 second delay)
test2 
(2 second delay)
test3
```

Comment: Why not use `setInterval` and process your queue from there, one at a fime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply your delay by the index

```
var myArray = ['test1','test2','test3'];

function doSetTimeout(index) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(myArray[index]) }, index * 2000;
}

var index;
for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; ++index) {
    doSetTimeout(index)
}
```